# How to tell the parent-child relationship of shell processes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example, use "bash" command to create a new child process from the process ID 84982:

```
$ echo $$
84982
$ bash
$ echo $$
86616
```

By looking at the PIDs, How can I tell the relationship between the two processes? Is that child's PID MUST be greater than the parent's PID?

Comment: I'm sure the Linux OS is rather busy in performing other tasks  than running a complex code for selecting a child process ID which has a relationship with its parent. The answer is no :)

Comment: `pstree -p`  Is it what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are given is two process IDs, there is no way to tell which is the parent and which is the child, or if one is even an ancestor of the other. Process IDs are assigned in order as processes are created, using the next largest (modulo 65535) unused ID available at the time.

You can, however, examine the value of `PPID` in the shell to see who the parent process is.

```
bash-4.3$ echo $$
45564
bash-4.3$ bash
bash-4.3$ echo $$
45565
bash-4.3$ echo $PPID
45564
bash-4.3$
```

Comment: You say "there is no way" and then you show a way. Perhaps clarify the wording in the first sentence -- "there is no way just by looking at them" or some such?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of commands that can help you achieve this:

1) Check parent PID `ps` : 
`$ ps -o ppid=$PPID`

2) Print the process tree `pstree` : 
`$ pstree -g $PPID`